# Addin up in foreach from JSON PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am trying to add up in a `foreach` from JSON format.

What I am after doing is adding up "totalDamageDealtToChampions" for team="100" and then adding up also for team="200" inside a foreach. I currently have this:

```
$getTeamIDMatchHistory10 = $statSummaryzzhistory->teamId;


foreach($match_content->participants as $statSummaryzMatchhistoryz) {

    if($statSummaryzMatchhistoryz->teamId == 100){              
        $sumteamiddmg1 += $statSummaryzMatchhistoryz->stats->totalDamageDealtToChampions;

    } else if ($statSummaryzMatchhistoryz->teamId == 200){
        $sumteamiddmg2 += $statSummaryzMatchhistoryz->stats->totalDamageDealtToChampions;
    } 
}
if($getTeamIDMatchHistory10 == 100){
    echo $sumteamiddmg1;
} else if ($getTeamIDMatchHistory10 == 200) {
    echo $sumteamiddmg2;
}
```

From this Data

```
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 3,
      "spell2Id": 4,
      "championId": 53,
      "highestAchievedSeasonTier": "SILVER",
      "timeline": {
        "creepsPerMinDeltas": {
          "zeroToTen": 0.4,
          "tenToTwenty": 0.9,
          "twentyToThirty": 0.8999999999999999,
          "thirtyToEnd": 0.8
        },
        "xpPerMinDeltas": {
          "zeroToTen": 299,
          "tenToTwenty": 283.6,
          "twentyToThirty": 407,
          "thirtyToEnd": 498
        },
        "goldPerMinDeltas": {
          "zeroToTen": 160.3,
          "tenToTwenty": 264.7,
          "twentyToThirty": 334.4,
          "thirtyToEnd": 369.6
        },
        "csDiffPerMinDeltas": {
          "zeroToTen": -0.6000000000000001,
          "tenToTwenty": -1.1,
          "twentyToThirty": -0.5500000000000003,
          "thirtyToEnd": -3.1999999999999997
        },
        "xpDiffPerMinDeltas": {
          "zeroToTen": 6.700000000000017,
          "tenToTwenty": 11.150000000000006,
          "twentyToThirty": -152.30000000000004,
          "thirtyToEnd": -602.0000000000002
        },
        "damageTakenPerMinDeltas": {
          "zeroToTen": 320.5,
          "tenToTwenty": 658.2,
          "twentyToThirty": 823.6,
          "thirtyToEnd": 1770.8
        },
        "damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas": {
          "zeroToTen": 12.599999999999966,
          "tenToTwenty": 165.65,
          "twentyToThirty": -70,
          "thirtyToEnd": 104.5
        },
        "role": "DUO_SUPPORT",
        "lane": "BOTTOM"
      },
      "masteries": [
        {
          "masteryId": 6211,
          "rank": 5
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6223,
          "rank": 1
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6232,
          "rank": 5
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6241,
          "rank": 1
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6311,
          "rank": 5
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6322,
          "rank": 1
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6332,
          "rank": 5
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6342,
          "rank": 1
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6352,
          "rank": 5
        },
        {
          "masteryId": 6362,
          "rank": 1
        }
      ],
      "stats": {
        "winner": false,
        "champLevel": 15,
        "item0": 3001,
        "item1": 2049,
        "item2": 3069,
        "item3": 3191,
        "item4": 3158,
        "item5": 3108,
        "item6": 3364,
        "kills": 3,
        "doubleKills": 0,
        "tripleKills": 0,
        "quadraKills": 0,
        "pentaKills": 0,
        "unrealKills": 0,
        "largestKillingSpree": 2,
        "deaths": 7,
        "assists": 14,
        "totalDamageDealt": 29026,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions": 14117,
        "totalDamageTaken": 31337,
        "largestCriticalStrike": 0,
        "totalHeal": 3257,
        "minionsKilled": 27,
        "neutralMinionsKilled": 0,
        "neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle": 0,
        "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle": 0,
        "goldEarned": 11133,
        "goldSpent": 9575,
        "combatPlayerScore": 0,
        "objectivePlayerScore": 0,
        "totalPlayerScore": 0,
        "totalScoreRank": 0,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions": 10808,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions": 3183,
        "trueDamageDealtToChampions": 124,
        "visionWardsBoughtInGame": 3,
        "sightWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
        "magicDamageDealt": 21242,
        "physicalDamageDealt": 7658,
        "trueDamageDealt": 124,
        "magicDamageTaken": 10474,
        "physicalDamageTaken": 18037,
        "trueDamageTaken": 2825,
        "firstBloodKill": false,
        "firstBloodAssist": false,
        "firstTowerKill": false,
        "firstTowerAssist": false,
        "firstInhibitorKill": false,
        "firstInhibitorAssist": false,
        "inhibitorKills": 0,
        "towerKills": 0,
        "wardsPlaced": 24,
        "wardsKilled": 6,
        "largestMultiKill": 1,
        "killingSprees": 1,
        "totalUnitsHealed": 1,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt": 203
      },
      "participantId": 1,
      "runes": [
        {
          "runeId": 5255,
          "rank": 9
        },
        {
          "runeId": 5289,
          "rank": 9
        },
        {
          "runeId": 5317,
          "rank": 9
        },
        {
          "runeId": 5347,
          "rank": 1
        },
        {
          "runeId": 5357,
          "rank": 2
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: So what is the issue you need us to help with?

Comment: In other words, what is the issue that you are having with the code? If it's producing an unexpected result then can you show us that output?